# Improvement of code precision using NDSolve for Differential-Algebraic equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, physics

I'm trying to solve a system of 24 non-linear Differential-Algebraic equations (DAE). I'm using the command NDSolve in Mathematica to solve this system, using this command, the error is too much large. I want to improve the precision of the code, for this I was trying different methods in NDSolve command. But, Mathematica is unable to solve. I'm getting the error:

NDSolve::nodae: The method NDSolve`FixedStep is not currently implemented to solve differential-algebraic equations. Use Method -> Automatic instead.

I want to use the Implicit-Runge-Kutta method or projection method to improve my results.

If I used these methods in a system of ODE's in NDSolve command, mathematica is able to give output.

Just as an example to test the code, I'm posting here some short example:

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t], y'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 0.1, y[0] == 0}, {x, 
  y}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 Method -> {"FixedStep", 
   Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 10, 
     "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision, 
       PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision, 
       "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}}}, StartingStepSize -> 1/10]
```

I'm able to obtain the output of the above system using Implicit-Runge-Kutta method, but If I use DAE system, I'm not able to get output, for example:

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] - y[t] == Sin[t], x[t] + y[t] == 1, x[0] == 0}, {x, 
  y}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 Method -> {"FixedStep", 
   Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 10, 
     "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", AccuracyGoal -> 15, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 50, "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}}}, 
 StartingStepSize -> 1/10]
```

Can anyone help me please, how can I solve such a DAE system with NDSolve command using some implicit method, like Implicit-Runge-Kutta method?

Should I convert this DAE system into ODE's, if yes then how can we convert such a system into a system of ordinary differential equations?

Actually, I'm working in General Relativity, here to apply the method as for the above example is not simple. I'm still not able to solve the system. I'm posting here my system of DAE equations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115050/discussion-on-question-by-mms-improvement-of-code-precision-using-ndsolve-for-di).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MichaelE2 already has answered the question in a comment: To use `Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"`, differentiate the second equation and add a corresponding boundary condition for `y`.  However, the OP expressed the concern that doing so might produce an inaccurate answer.  Out of curiosity, I tried it.  So, the following actually is an extended comment.

It is easy to determine the accuracy of any numerical solution to the system of equations, because a symbolic solution exists.

```
sa = DSolveValue[{x'[t] - y[t] == Sin[t], x[t] + y[t] == 1, x[0] == 0}, 
    {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
(* {1/2 (2 - E^-t - Cos[t] + Sin[t]), 1/2 (E^-t + Cos[t] - Sin[t])} *)
```

Then, applying the approach recommended by MichaelE2,

```
NDSolveValue[{x'[t] - y[t] == Sin[t], x'[t] + y'[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, 
   {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta", InterpolationOrder -> All];
```

yields excellent accuracy.

```
Plot[Evaluate[% - sa], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, "x,y"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Note that `InterpolationOrder -> All` is needed to eliminate spurious oscillations in the `InterpolationFunction` of order `10^-5`.  Whether this approach can be used in the 24-equation system mentioned by the OP depends on the details of those equations, which I have requested.

Incidentally, I find it surprising that `NDSolve` does not simplify the original DAE system to eliminate `y[t]` and numerically integrate the resulting ODE in `x[t]`, instead of terminating when `Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"` is employed.

**Addendum: Solution to set of 24 nonlinear equations**

`NDSolve` misinterprets the system of enormous equations recently added to the question as a DAE system due to

```
Vup = {Vt[τ], Vr[τ], Vθ[τ], Vϕ[τ]};
```

These four quantities are, in fact, simply names for expressions and should be renamed as

```
Vup = {Vt, Vr, Vθ, Vϕ};
```

The code giving them values then becomes

```
{Vt, Vr, Vθ, Vϕ} = NN (Wvec + Pup) /. t -> t[τ] /. r -> r[τ] /. θ -> θ[τ] /. ϕ -> ϕ[τ];
```

instead of the expression for `EQ4`.  Of course, `EQ4` then must be deleted from the subsequent expression for `EOM`.  The code leading to `EOM` also has an error somewhere, which I corrected rather inelegantly by inserting after the expression for `EOM` the further line of code,

```
EOM = EOM /. z_[τ][τ] -> z[τ];
```

With these changes `NDSolve` successfully runs until `r[τ]` decreases to `2`, the event horizon.  Specifically,

```
var = Through[{t, r, θ, ϕ, Pt, Pr, Pθ, Pϕ, Stt, Str, Stθ, Stϕ, 
    Srt, Srr, Srθ, Srϕ, Sθt, Sθr, Sθθ, Sθϕ, Sϕt, Sϕr, Sϕθ, Sϕϕ}[τ]];
NDSolveValue[Flatten[Join[{EOM, INT}]], var, {τ, 0, 1000}, 
    Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta"}];
```

terminates with `NDSolveValue::ndsz` at `τ = 37.771696`.  A plot of the first eight variables then is,

```
Plot[Evaluate[%[[;; 8]]], {τ, 0, 37.77169}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, 8}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Placed[ToString /@ var, {.35, .6}]]
```

[image]

The remaining dependent variables are identically zero.

Comment: Er… what do you mean by "I find it surprising that NDSolve does not simplify the system before starting the numerical integration"?

Comment: @xzczd  Good question.  I have clarified my final sentence.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thank for your great efforts, how can be the dependent variables zero? Even the posted code was giving the solution for all 24 variables. I used the approach you have mentioned but Mathematica is giving error:: DSolve::underdet: here are more dependent variables, than equations, so the system is underdetermined. I think we should adopt some different command together with the ImplicitRungeKutta command to solve such a system. I was following this, [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html), but unfortunately was not successful.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks a lot for your great efforts, now I'm able to run the code without any error. Actually, I changed the initial conditions, now I am able to obtain  the solutions for all 24 variables.

Comment: @MMS  You are welcome.  I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, sure, I will follow your suggestions, and thanks for guidance.